# How set short month names using ember-moment

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I need to change short month in moment.
But I can't do it.
I have try to set

```
localeOutputPath: 'assets/moment-locales'
```

And call

```
Ember.$.getScript('/assets/moment-locales/ru.js');
```

In this case i have ember-mirage error

```
 Your Ember app tried to GET '/assets/moment-locales/ru.js?_=1490191145335',
 but there was no route defined to handle this request. Define a route that
 matches this path in your mirage/config.js file
```

Is it simple way to set short months name for moment?

Comment: is there anything not clear about my answer? please clone the source code I provided and ask further questions if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using `ember-moment` addon; and already have configured `config/environment.js` with

```
moment: {
  // This will output _all_ locale scripts to assets/moment-locales
  localeOutputPath: 'assets/moment-locales'
},
```

as you have mentioned.

```
Ember.$.getScript('/assets/moment-locales/ru.js');
```

provides a way to dynamically load moment `ru` locale on the fly when needed. This means instead of including the related locale to your application's javascript file you prefer to load relevant locale upon some user request in your application. Generally it is best to perform such loading operation within a router's hook methods such as `beforeModel` or `model`.

In order to get short month names from `moment`; you need to first import ES6 `moment` module via

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

and access the short month names with

```
moment.monthsShort()
```

As far as I can see; there is a problem with the way you are requesting the locale so you are getting the error you have mentioned. I believe a working code is a better explanation from pure text; hence I have created the following [git repository](https://github.com/feanor07/ember-dynamic-moment-locale-loading) to illustrate how you can change the locale dynamically in a route and how you can display short names retrieved from `moment`. Please take a look at it by cloning and running in your localhost.

In the application at this repository, `application.hbs` contains links to 5 sub-routes; each displaying short names of months in different languages. The code that does the trick of dynamically loading the relevant locale is in `routes/locale-route.js` file's `model` hook method. If locale is already loaded (note that English is included by default with `moment`) it simply returns the short names of the months via switching to target locale (`moment.locale(localeToLoad);`). Otherwise, it performs a remote call to the server and waits for the response (by using a promise) to return the name of months. All routes for 5 different languages extend from this base route. Once, a locale is loaded from the server; you no longer need to load it again once more and the `locale-route` already handles it as I explained. I hope that helps.

After reading your comment; I updated the source code to include `ember-cli-mirage`. Mirage is a client-side mock server to develop, test and prototype your application. Once you include it as a dependency it starts intercepting your remote call requests. Hence, in your case mirage intercepts requests for demanding related locale. What you need to do is passing through mirage for locales. In order to do that, you need to add following

```
this.passthrough('/assets/moment-locales/**');
```

to `mirage/config.js` so that mirage will not interfere with demanding moment-locales at the runtime. Please see [related file](https://github.com/feanor07/ember-dynamic-moment-locale-loading/blob/master/mirage/config.js) under the git repository I have provided. This will solve your problem for sure.

Comment: Call Ember.$.getScript('/assets/moment-locales/ru.js'); is bad decision because this call wil be catch by Ember-mirage and will fail with error that it can't process this URL.

Comment: @AlexeyVashchenkov mirage is a client-side mock server to develop, test and prototype; so it will not be available in real production. I have no idea why mirage intercepts your call to dynamically load locale. You said "Call Ember.$.getScript('/assets/moment-locales/ru.js'); is bad decision "'; i do not agree with that. It is the suggested way to dynamically load locales as indicated in [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment). Your question is not clear, at least for me. Do you need to load locales on demand or not?

Comment: @AlexeyVashchenkov i understood your question better now and I updated the answer. Please try what I wrote and look at my source code (I have now included mirage as it is in your case!). Do not forget to accept and upvote please :)

Comment: Yes this work if I use     Ember.$.getScript('/assets/moment-locales/ru.js');
in route file.
But unfortunataly       localeOutputPath: 'assets/moment-locales'
doesn't work.