# Ember-moment how to format the date/time according to locale

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I'm stick with how to format a date/time using [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment) add-on using a browser locale. I defined the included locales in `environment.js`as explained in their README:

```
moment: {
  includeLocales: true
}
```

Then in a handlbars template I try to display the date:

```
{{moment-format urrentShop.shop.openingDate 'L'}}
```

But the date is still displayed in US format:

```
03/27/2018
```

instead of the French one. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42953910/4131048) question could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [ember-i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n) add-on. I set up the locale detection as described in their docs:

```
#app/instance-intializers/i18n.js

export function initialize(applicationInstance) {
  let i18n = applicationInstance.lookup('service:i18n');
  let moment = applicationInstance.lookup('service:moment');
  let locale = calculateLocale(i18n.get('locales'));
  i18n.set('locale', locale);  
  moment.setLocale(locale);
}

function calculateLocale(locales) {
  // whatever you do to pick a locale for the user:
  const language = navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

  return  locales.includes(language.toLowerCase()) ? language : 'en-GB';
}

export default {
  name: 'i18n',
  initialize
};
```

As you can see, I had to add:

```
let moment = applicationInstance.lookup('service:moment');
moment.setLocale(locale);
```

to set the locale on `moment` service.
I also added to the `environment.js`:

```
moment: {
  includeLocales: true
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ember-moment defaults to locale `en`. You can change it at runtime with `this.get('moment').setLocale('fr');` (see [ember-moment/readme](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment#configure-default-runtime-localetimezone)):

```
// app/routes/applicaton.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  moment: Ember.inject.service(),
  beforeModel() {
    this.get('moment').setLocale('fr');
  }
});
```

To use the browsers locale:

```
// app/routes/applicaton.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  moment: Ember.inject.service(),
  beforeModel() {
    let locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language; // e.g. fr-FR
    if (locale) {
      this.get('moment').setLocale(locale.substr(0,2));
    }
  }
});
```